# compress and decompress video on windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a bunch of videos (~770 mb) of mp4 videos that i would like to include in my app. Due to the fact that the .xap is limited to 225 mb, i am trying to get as much as possible in the app (so to avoid streaming). Is there a way to compress my videos and decompress them on my windows phone 7?

Comment: If the videos are mp4, they are already compressed. "Decompression" occurs in realtime when the video is played. What you can do is "re-compress" the same video to a different bitrate, thus reducing its size.

Comment: @Marek i was thinking that the files could be converted to a more space-efficient format. Wouldn't want to modif the bitrate, seems that i can't escape streaming..

Comment: Since there is no way to losslessly compress them more, you may consider including lower resolution and/or bitrate files in the xap and allowing the downloading of the full quality videos. That gives your users some options anyway.